# SQL CASE WHEN still reading field even if it is not used

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have simple SQL query:

```
DECLARE @flag bit = 0;
SELECT TOP (100000) 
      [Id]
      CASE WHEN @flag=1 THEN [Description] END
FROM [dbo].[ReallyBigTable]
```

Description is a very very big field and variable flag here is just filter of fields, pretty much constant most of the time, but comparison of execution plans of similar query:

```
SELECT TOP (100000) 
      [Id]
FROM [dbo].[ReallyBigTable]
```

Gives me information that Description in first query is actually readen! It is not returned but I/O on disk is there. In second case there is no much I/O on disk, and query executes very fast. Ratio between two is ~25, so second query have 25 lower I/O than first one.

Why in first case field is readen though is is not used?

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server has to compile an execution plan that is valid for any value of the parameter `@flag` (in this case it is a variable rather than a parameter but same applies as the statement is compiled before the variable is even assigned and with no knowledge about its value taken into account).

The simplest way of doing that is just to pull back `[Description]` and evaluate the `CASE` at runtime. This is what it does.

If you are not happy with this you can add `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` to get the statement recompiled after the variable is assigned. This plan is not cached and only needs to be valid for the specific value known at compile time. This "parameter embedding optimisation" allows the reference to `Description` to be simplified out if `@flag=1` is not true. This does mean every execution is recompiled however.

Or alternatively you can just separate out into different statements that are optimised separately - or combine them with `UNION ALL` and `WHERE`

```
DECLARE @flag bit = 0;
SELECT [Id],
       [Description]
FROM [dbo].[ReallyBigTable]
WHERE @flag=1
UNION ALL
SELECT [Id],
       NULL
FROM [dbo].[ReallyBigTable]
WHERE @flag = 0 OR @flag IS NULL
```

To get a plan with two branches with filters with startup predicates so only the relevant one is executed at run time.

Comment: Thank you for insight! Though it is really sad news for Entity Frameworks and me, it doesn't have exclusion of fields and I need some way to hack this around =/

Comment: @eocron - It's a while since I looked at EF but I thought it generated SELECT statements that only select the columns you project? So you would need to do the conditional logic that projects the right object for the flag in the .NET side I would have thought

Comment: Yeah, but permutation of fields is still impossible: select (a,b) (b,c) (a,c) ....